# Query Optimitize

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below query is running for 7hrs. Can anyone help me to optimize the query?

```
select    count(1) 
FROM      temp_raw_appointments trp
left join temp_raw_transactions_sep tra
on        case  when tra.[rndrng prvdr] in (SELECT [rndrng prvdr] 
                                            FROM   temp_raw_changetosupprov)
                     then tra.[sup prvdr] 
                when tra.[rndrng prvdr] = 'P003_BMI_WidermannJ' 
                     then 'P003_WiedermannJ' -- Kim Chirayil's customization, 06/16
                when tra.[rndrng prvdr] = 'P014_HeerenK' 
                     then 'P014_HarrisonL' -- Kim Chirayil's customization, 06/16
                else tra.[rndrng prvdr] end 
          =trp.[appt schdlng prvdr] 
where     tra.[rndrng prvdr] is null
```

Comment: whats your execution plan like? you can use 'where not exists' instead of 'where is null' that should help out

Comment: What are the tables' keys? What indexes do you have on the tables?

Comment: Can you paste us the query execution plan here ? https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the query into two parts

```
CREATE TABLE #inter
  (
     temp_col VARCHAR(500)
  )

INSERT INTO #inter
SELECT Distinct CASE
         WHEN tra.[rndrng prvdr] IN (SELECT [rndrng prvdr]
                                     FROM   temp_raw_changetosupprov) THEN tra.[sup prvdr]
         WHEN tra.[rndrng prvdr] = 'P003_BMI_WidermannJ' THEN 'P003_WiedermannJ' -- Kim Chirayil's customization, 06/16
         WHEN tra.[rndrng prvdr] = 'P014_HeerenK' THEN 'P014_HarrisonL' -- Kim Chirayil's customization, 06/16
         ELSE tra.[rndrng prvdr]
       END AS temp_col
FROM   temp_raw_transactions_sep tra

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nix_inter
  ON #inter (temp_col)

SELECT Count(1)
FROM   temp_raw_appointments trp
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   #inter
                   WHERE  trp.[appt schdlng prvdr] = temp_col)
```

Since it is running for past 7 hours I am not expecting execution plan. If you have one please provide to suggest further

Comment: I was checking your answer as well as profile. Would you explain in chat in general, about how to tackle problems related to `optimisation` ?

Comment: @PrabhatG - Splitting the code is not the right way to optimize but I felt here it could make a difference. But only by testing we can conclude.  Optimization includes so many factors. It starts from table design, Index, statistics, proper usage of joins etc..

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Updated logic of joining conditions. this may help for performance tuning.

```
select count(1) 
FROM temp_raw_appointments trp
left join temp_raw_transactions_sep tra on (tra.[sup prvdr] = trp.[appt schdlng prvdr]  AND EXIST (SELECT 1 FROM temp_raw_changetosupprov [rndrng prvdr] =tra.[rndrng prvdr])
OR ( trp.[appt schdlng prvdr] = tra.[rndrng prvdr] AND tra.[rndrng prvdr] IN ('P003_BMI_WidermannJ','P014_HeerenK'))
OR (tra.[rndrng prvdr] = trp.[appt schdlng prvdr] )   
where tra.[rndrng prvdr] is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it will be nice to see the execution plan, execution stats, and rows count, but, consider this educated guess as a possible solution:

1) make sure that tra.[rndrng prvdr] (ideally with [sup prvdr] included column or second key in the index), temp_raw_changetosupprov.[rndrng prvdr], trp.[appt schdlng prvdr] columns are indexed.
2) Rewrite the query to make it more efficient. Since you are interested only in IS NULL rows after LEFT JOIN, I guess the logic of the following query will be correct:

```
WITH SupPrvdr([sup prvdr])
AS
(
    SELECT tra.[sup prvdr] FROM temp_raw_transactions_sep tra
    WHERE tra.[rndrng prvdr] IN
    (
        SELECT [rndrng prvdr] FROM temp_raw_changetosupprov
        UNION 
        SELECT 'P003_WiedermannJ' AS [rndrng prvdr] 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'P014_HarrisonL'AS [rndrng prvdr] 
    ) 
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_raw_appointments trp
WHERE trp.[appt schdlng prvdr] NOT IN (SELECT [sup prvdr] FROM SupPrvdr)
    OR trp.[appt schdlng prvdr] IS NULL -- if trp.[appt schdlng prvdr] is nullable column this condition can be omitted
```